Accessing the RTCRootView appProperties from Expo
I am building a React Native application (and am primarily concerned with the iOS implementation) with Expo and need to access the root view to set appProperties. I've noticed that Expo abstracts this away in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:. Is there a supported way to get a reference to this or appProperties, or do I need to edit the Expo source? I couldn't find this in the documentation; apologies if I missed this.
I have tried searching the documentation as well as forking the expo source code, but I don't like this approach as it's a little "hack-y". Also, ejecting expo is depreciated though it looked like that might make it easier to achieve what I'm looking for.

One solution I've been able to come up with for now is creating a CommunicationView. This view just handles communication with the native code through retaining event handlers, which will re-add new event handlers once consumed (I think this is safe because, checking the reference to the react component; if not found, the handler will not be run). This is still a little hacky, but I think better than the other solutions.
